# Heroku app's Bundler is running the wrong version of Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, bundler

I have a Rails Heroku app that uses Ruby 2.6.5 and Rails 6.0.2.2. This is a [supported Ruby version](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#ruby-versions) by Heroku, and I've specified it in .ruby-version, my Gemfile, and Gemfile.lock:

```
~ $ cat .ruby-version 
2.6.5
~ $ cat Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.5'
[...]
~ $ cat Gemfile.lock
[...]
RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.6.5p114
```

However, when I run `bundler env` on the remote application, this is the first part of the output:

```
~ $ bundle env
## Environment

Bundler       2.0.2
  Platforms   ruby, x86_64-linux
Ruby          2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
  Full Path   /usr/bin/ruby2.5
  Config Dir  /etc
RubyGems      2.7.6
  Gem Home    /var/lib/gems/2.5.0
  Gem Path    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0:
  User Path   /app/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  Bin Dir     /usr/local/bin
Tools         
  Git         2.17.1
  RVM         not installed
  rbenv       not installed
  chruby      not installed
```

Note that it's using Ruby 2.5.1. This is preventing me from running Rails migrations, because I always get the error `Your Ruby version is 2.5.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.6.5`. Am I missing something?

Things I've tried, which didn't cause any change in behavior:

- Starting a brand new Heroku application using the app, with a fresh deploy
- Running `/bin/bash` on the Heroku application and manually updating Bundler

Is there any way to get Bundler to use the right version of Ruby?

Comment: Does it work if you try a new `heroku run bash`? Otherwise you can try to run the migration by `heroku run rails db:migrate`. Or contact support.

Comment: Which version of rails are you using?

Comment: @JuanitoFatas It does seem to work from `heroku run bash`, with the caveat that you can't perform the migration using `bundle exec`. This at least solves my problem in the short term, although I'm still confused about bundler's ruby version.

Comment: @PetrGazarov This is Rails 6.0.2.2, editing into the question.

Comment: When you run `git push heroku master`, what is the output after `Building source:`? Which ruby version does it say in `Using Ruby version:`